# Is there any good references for i18n and L10n in ISO C++?

Tags: c++, localization, internationalization, locale

There is a header (" < locale > ") in Standard ISO C++.

Is there any good references for Internationalization and localization in ISO C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best sources I know are:

- *Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales* by Langer and Kraft (it has a tutorial part and a more reference part)
- the appendix in some version of the third edition of *The C++ Programming Language* by Stroustrup (which is also available [online](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_loc.pdf)) is more a user guide than a reference
- the relevant section in the standard is only a reference and not suitable as a user guide.

Answer (score 4):

No.

There are references on how to use C++ streams and the locale facets... but ISO C++ does not provide a way for true Internalization/Localization.

The subject is much more difficult than it appears, because some languages have arcane rules

- in Greek, the `tolower` method would require looking at the whole word, instead of just the current character because `toupper` is not injective.
- in Spanish, `ll` is a letter itself (although two distinct tokens), with its own place in the alphabet.

And I won't even start on the ordinals in Polish...

If you really want proper I18n/L10n in C++, you may turn toward the ICU library, which despite its C-ish interface, is the de-facto standard. For translation of content, you may want to look at GetText (a GNU project). The two can be combined to obtain both translation and manipulation of internationalized resources, like translating a list of items and rendering it sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I'd say ICU had a Java'ish interface (not a big improvement)

Comment: @jalf: I am more complaining about the weirdness that comes of manipulating raw pointers and representing results in "surprising" types, for example: at http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html `int8_t UnicodeString::compare(UChar const*, int32_t);` feels very C-ish... The result type is plain weird (reminiscent of `strcmp` though) and the length parameter being signed is reminiscent of the pervasive use of `int` in C (Not to even mention the manipulation of an array through a pointer + length couple...) I do feel the Java-ish influence too though, not pleasant either :/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/) is online reference manual.